# Reversible and Irreversible processes

Tags: thermodynamics

In an ideal world, is moving a piston quickly, a reversible process as there is no heat loss due to friction? (as opposed to a quasi static process)

Comment: Quickly excludes reversible, friction or not.

Comment: Why would moving a piston quickly reduce frictional heating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving a piston rapidly results in an adiabatic process, not an irreversible process.  In a rapid compression or expansion, viscous dissipation of mechanical energy to internal energy is irreversible.

Comment: Hm, IMHO, fast piston movement may or may not lead to reversible process even without such dissipation. If I compress an ideal gas system adiabatically and expand isothermally  to the initial state, surrounding will not return to the initial state, as I have converted some work to heat.

Comment: Additionally, are not reversible processes always in equilibrium state, therefore idealistic regardless of dissipation?

Comment: @Poutnik There is negligible viscous dissipation in a reversible process.

Comment: Still, lack of dissipation is essential but not sufficient condition for process reversibility. Dissipationless cycle of adiabatic compression, cooling and isothermal expansion converts work to heat. But you cannot reverse it to convert heat to work. But I will be happy if I realize I am wrong.

Comment: In my understanding, reversible process, if a system is brought to the initial state, surrounding is brought to initial state as well ( in absence of own external processes ). Or vice versa, bringing surrounding to initial state brings the system to the initial state too.

Comment: *In thermodynamics, a reversible process is a process whose direction can be reversed to return the system to its original state by inducing infinitesimal changes to some property of the system's surroundings.  Throughout the entire reversible process, the system is in thermodynamic equilibrium with its surroundings.* [Wikipedia reversible process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_%28thermodynamics%29)